# Connecting points on a surface plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I am working on a project where we make measurements in a linear fashion and rotate the sample in order to produce a 3D surface map.

The data comes from a polar format, we have 4 datasets:

```
theta = 0  , r = -20 -- 20
theta = 45 , r = -20 -- 20
theta = 90 , r = -20 -- 20
theta = 135, r = -20 -- 20
```

I can transform this into cartesian points by generating x and y vectors with sin and cos and plotting the result against that matrix.

So an example "ready to plot" matrix set looks something like this:

```
x [4x21 double]
-20    -18    -16 ..
-14.14 -12.73 -11.31 ..
0      0      0 ..
..

y [4x21 double]
0      0      0 ..
-14.14 -12.73 -11.31 ..
-20    -18    -16 ..
..

z [4x21 double]
.224 .281 .320 ..
.228 .280 .312 ..
.282 .349 .377 ..
..
```

The output surface plot with some basic formatting is like this:
[image: cartesian surface of the above data]

Matlab is connecting between the vectors which I want.  However, it is not connecting the 90-degree rotation to the 135-degree rotation.  How do I make it do this?

The basic code to produce a figure similar to the example above is this:

```
theta = [ 0 , -45 , -90 , -135];
r = -20 : 2 : 20;
for i = 1 : 4
    xc(i,:) = r .* cosd(theta(i));
    yc(i,:) = r .* sind(theta(i));
    zc(i,:) = [[0 : 0.1 : 0.9] , [1 : -0.1 : 0]];
end
figure
surf(xc,yc,zc);
```

Comment: You can also use `pol2cart` to convert from polar to Cartesian coordinates. Are you plotting with `surf`?

Comment: @David it is preferable to do polar to cartesian coordinates manually, as I only use one value of rho per 21 values of r.  I am indeed plotting with surf.  The values of x are positive to negative for the fourth row of the x and y vectors.

Comment: OK, I don't think I can help unless you make a [mcve] so that people can play around with the code.

Comment: @David I added example code.  The values of z are, in this case, meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do `theta=-180` explicitly. Just like `plot` doesn't wrap-around and join the first and last points, `surf` wont connect the first "edge" to the last "edge". Make `theta=[0 -45 -90 -135 -180]` and do `for i=1:5` and it should be good.

[image]

You'll find the colouring looks a bit weird, this might look better depending on the application: `surf(xc,yc,zc,'FaceColor','interp')`.

[image]

A better way to create your data could be

```
[R,TH]=meshgrid(r,theta);
[xc,yc]=pol2cart(TH*pi/180,R);
zc = repmat([[0 : 0.1 : 0.9] , [1 : -0.1 : 0]],length(theta),1);
```